# Yarn serve command serves old file version on WSL

Tags: node.js, vue.js, yarnpkg, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to run developer server in WSL with a simple genertated Vue App. Project is served by `yarn serve` command. Yarn does not react on file changes even when server is restarted by `yarn serve` command. It simply serves old files and content of the browser does not change.

Changes are visible only when new content is downloaded via `git pull` command. `yarn build` works correctly, I can see changes in compiled file.

What have I done already:

1. Updated node (v10.16.3), npm (6.9.0) and yarn (1.17.3) respectively.
2. Cleared yarn cache
3. Reinstalled node_modules
4. Disabled cache in Chrome DevTools

Comment: Did you change the files in windows or in WSL?

Comment: I was changing file content in Windows using VSC. It works now I've provided an answer below.

Comment: Just wanted to add [this blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/) and its reminder to never change files within the WSL directories from Windows; only change files in Windows directories and access them via `/mnt/` in WSL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some extend reserch I've transfered project into `<username>/mnt/d/` directory of WSL and downloaded repository as non-root user (previously all project files were created by root in root directory). And it worked. Now, with correct permissions `yarn serve` can watch file changes and serve fresh content.